# Which is better way for creating factory class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have created factory class and i wonder which is better way to implement it.
option 1

```
public class Factory {

    private IProperty prop;
    public IDoc doc;

    public Factory(int version) {
        switch (version) {
            case '1':   
                prop = new Prop();
                doc = new Docu();
        ...
            case '2':
            prop = new Prop1();
            doc = new Docu1();
        ...
        }
    }

    public IProperty getProperty() {
        return this.prop;
    }

    public IDoc getDoc() {
        return this.doc;
    }
}
```

My question is if to do it like that i.e. define member with the interface type and to to switch on the constructor or for every get method to use switch statement instead on the constructor, so in the constructor i will just get the
version and save it on class member and than for instance use like

```
public IProperty getProperty() {
switch (version) {
  case '1':
    prop = new Prop();
  case '2':
    prop = new Prop1();
...
```

So what is the better way, or any other idea?

Comment: Your first version will not even compile. Your switch is outside any method. Its not allowed. And as per your question, 2nd option is always a better way to go. Let the `getProperty` method decide how it builds the `property`.

Comment: One more question, why your factory have non-static reference instead of static references?

Comment: Either 1st or 2nd way is possible - they have minor difference. In the  1st case `IProperty`/`IDoc` instances returned by the same instance of `Factory` will always be the same, while in 2nd case there is still a possibility to change instances returned by `Factory` instance during it's lifetime. Though presence of `switch` statement clearly indicates that polymorphism can (and actually should) be used instead of it - please refer to `bobah` answer which  describes how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all, your `Factory` should ideally have `static references`
  instead of `non-static` one. And it should have a `static method` to *create / get*
  the appropriate instance.
- Secondly, its better to have *two different factories* for different
  types.
- Thirdly, I would name your method as `createProperty`, rather than
  `getPropertyObject`, because that method is not returning the already
  created instance, rather its creating one.

Of course, `getPropertyObject('1')`, seems like it is fetching a `property` for that version from a persistence storage, which is not what it is doing. It is rather creating an instance based on version.

(**NOTE: -** Name of `static factory methods` are important. They are amongst one of the advantages, they have over `constructors`. Since with a `name`, you can guess what exactly that `factory method` does)

Having said that, I would say, that the `2nd option` would be better with all those changes. Let the `createProperty` method decide, how it wants to create the `instance`.

So, I would modify your code like this: -

```
public class PropertyFactory {
    private static IProperty prop;

    public static createProperty(char version) {

        switch (version) {
            case '1':
                prop = new Prop();
                break;  // Don't forget a `break` here.
            case '2':
               prop = new Prop1();
               break;

            default:  // do have a default case
               prop = null;
        } 
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Similarly, you can create a `DocumentFactory` to create a `document object`. Name the method: - `createDocument(char version)`

Answer (score 5):

The most clean way is to expose what you do as two separate factories giving them a common abstract base or a reusable policy argument if they have anything to share. One factory type should only create one type of particular object (say only plastic tools). Factory public configuration normally only holds properties required to create objects (contacts of suppliers, patents) or static properties of objects being created (type of plastic, let's say), but not type/class of objects.

Also, something that is a storage of long lived objects like in your example #1 should probably be called "context", not "factory".

Code example below.

```
public interface IFactory {
  IDoc createDoc();
  IProp createProp();
}

public class Type1Factory implements IFactory {
  @Override public IDoc createDoc() { return new Doc1(); }
  @Override public IProp createProp() { return new Prop1(); }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to write something similar but noticed this answer, thus adding +1 :)
The described way is actually called `Abstract Factory` pattern which one can easily google and which has a lot of benefits over other implementations.

Comment: +1 for this meaningful line ** One factory type should only create one type of particular object. **

Answer (score 0):

Your second way is always better since every caller of your `get*` methods will receive a new instance of the object. If you create the two objects in the constructor, you will have to handle object-sharing issues (even more if you use these objects in different threads).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of creating a factory is much better in your first version than second one.

Ideally, it shouldn't be the constructor of factory class but a static method.

```
public class Factory 
{
    public static IProperty getPropertyObject(char version)
    {
        switch (version)
        {
            case '1':
               return new Prop();

            case '2'
               return new Prop1();
        }
    }

    public static IDoc getDocObject(char version)
    {
        switch (version)
        {
            case '1':
               return new Doc();

            case '2'
               return new Doc1();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A static method would reduce testability as it would introduce a hard reference on a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your situation.

The first option suggests that your `IProperty` and `IDoc` have different versions but for each version of one you have a corresponding version of the other.

While the second option suggests that the versions of those could be independent of each other.